# How to get the name of the domain that is assigned to a specific field/column of a table?

Tags: sql, metadata, firebird, system-tables

I use a select from StackOverflow: [How can I get the table description (fields and types) from Firebird with dbExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070162/how-can-i-get-the-table-description-fields-and-types-from-firebird-with-dbexpr) to get schema-data of Firebird databases.

However, this select does not show the name of the domain that is assigned to a field/column.

Does anybody know the syntax to get the domain-name, too?

Comment: The column RDB$FIELD_SOURCE in the table RDB$RELATION_FIELDS hold the the field domain name.

Comment: See the official documentation about the System Tables: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-appx04-systables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column RDB$FIELD_SOURCE in the table RDB$RELATION_FIELDS hold the the field domain name. (@Marcodor)

Syntax:
RF.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE AS FIELD_DOMAIN,